# Creating a random Integer[] array of images from another Integer[] array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, random, integer, items

I am creating an activity that displays 9 images in a GridView. I want those images be selected randomly from an Integer[] array that contains 26 images. So my best approach is setting the 26 images fixed and then created a new array and fill using this simple method:

> ```
>     public Integer [] allLetters = {
>              R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
>              R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
>              R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f,
>              R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
>              R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j,
>              R.drawable.k, R.drawable.l,
>              R.drawable.m, R.drawable.m,
>              R.drawable.o, R.drawable.p,
>              R.drawable.q, R.drawable.r,
>              R.drawable.s, R.drawable.t,
>              R.drawable.u, R.drawable.v,
>              R.drawable.w, R.drawable.x,
>              R.drawable.y, R.drawable.z
>     };
>     private Integer[] randomLetters=null;
>     public int index=0;
>     public Random r= new Random();
>     public void creaArray() {
>         for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
>             index=r.nextInt(26);
>             randomLetters[i]=allLetters[index];
>         }
>     }
> ```

I thought this would fill randomLetters with 9 random values from allLetters but the app is "forced closing" me :( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes because you have not initialized the integer array. You must do something like this:

```
private Integer[] randomLetters = new Integer[9];
```

Bear in mind that your current algorithm could repeat some of the letters, which sometimes is an undesirable behavior.

Also, ready about how to use `adb logcat` in order to detect problems like this. You will save you and us a lot time.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Cristian and sorry about the logcat thing. I'm aware about it i just don't know how to use it YET. This activity is currently part of a project i have from college and i'm still learning some things.

Comment: Im not making any reference to "creaArray()" tho.. i think thats the problem. Already fixed the initialization thing.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks Cristian. I wasnt making any reference to creaArray();